# SQL pivot table eow into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a rate change history that I need to display in a different format. I'm thinking a PIVOT table may be able to help me.
My table is called ALL_RATES and the output looks like this:

```
ACC_NO  BAL     RATE    EFF_DT
1001    10000   3.5     01/01/2006
1001    12000   4.25    01/02/2006
1002    11000   3.25    01/02/2006
1002    11500   4.75    01/05/2006
1003    35000   3.5     01/01/2006
1003    0       0       01/05/2006
```

I would like to show only one account number per row as follows:

```
MONTH   01/01/2006     01/02/2006       01/03/2006      01/04/2006      01/05/2006      01/06/2006  
ACC_NO  BAL     RATE   BAL      RATE    BAL     RATE    BAL      RATE   BAL     RATE    BAL     RATE
1001    10000   3.5    12000    4.25    12000   4.25    12000    4.25   12000   4.25    12000   4.25
1002    0       0      11000    3.25    11000   3.25    11000    3.25   11500   4.75    11500   4.75
1003    35000   3.5    35000    3.5     35000   3.5     35000    3.5    0       0       0       0
```

Comment: What is your question?   Are you getting an error when you try to use PIVOT?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality using derived columns as follows:

```
    DECLARE     @MonthBal   VARCHAR(MAX)
        ,       @MonthRate  VARCHAR(MAX)
        ,       @Query  VARCHAR(MAX)


    CREATE TABLE [AccountDetails]
    (
        [ACC_NO]    INT
    ,   [BAL]       INT
    ,   [RATE]      DECIMAL(18, 2)
    ,   [EFF_DT]    DATE
    )

    CREATE TABLE [AccountDetailsDerived]
    (
        [ACC_NO]        INT
    ,   [BAL]           INT
    ,   [RATE]          DECIMAL(18, 2)
    ,   [EFF_DT_BAL]    VARCHAR(50)
    ,   [EFF_DT_RATE]   VARCHAR(50)
    )
```

I have declared two variables @MonthBal and @MonthRate to store the Rate and the month values respectively. I have also created a table with derived columns which you can create while selecting from the main table

Next I insert the mentioned data in the main table and the derived data in the second table:

```
    INSERT INTO [AccountDetails]
    (
        [ACC_NO]
    ,   [BAL]
    ,   [RATE]
    ,   [EFF_DT]
    )
    VALUES
        (1001,    10000,   3.5,     '01/01/2006')
    ,   (1001,    12000,   4.25,    '01/02/2006')
    ,   (1002,    11000,   3.25,    '01/02/2006')
    ,   (1002,    11500,   4.75,    '01/05/2006')
    ,   (1003,    35000,   3.5,     '01/01/2006')
    ,   (1003,    0,       0,       '01/05/2006')

    INSERT INTO [AccountDetailsDerived]
    (
        [ACC_NO]        
    ,   [BAL]           
    ,   [RATE]          
    ,   [EFF_DT_BAL]    
    ,   [EFF_DT_RATE]   
    )
    SELECT  [ACC_NO]
        ,   [BAL]   
        ,   [RATE]  
        ,   CONVERT(VARCHAR, [EFF_DT] ) + ' BAL'
        ,   CONVERT(VARCHAR, [EFF_DT] ) + ' RATE'
    FROM    [AccountDetails]
```

I query the derived table to see all the data is as I required it to be:

```
    SELECT * FROM [AccountDetailsDerived]
```

I get the resultset as:

```
    ACC_NO  | BAL   | RATE  | EFF_DT_BAL     |  EFF_DT_RATE
    1001    | 10000 | 3.50  | 2006-01-01 BAL |  2006-01-01 RATE
    1001    | 12000 | 4.25  | 2006-01-02 BAL |  2006-01-02 RATE
    1002    | 11000 | 3.25  | 2006-01-02 BAL |  2006-01-02 RATE
    1002    | 11500 | 4.75  | 2006-01-05 BAL |  2006-01-05 RATE
    1003    | 35000 | 3.50  | 2006-01-01 BAL |  2006-01-01 RATE
    1003    | 0     | 0.00  | 2006-01-05 BAL |  2006-01-05 RATE
```

Now I take the distinct months into the variables separately as follows:

```
    SELECT @MonthBal = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[EFF_DT_BAL]) + ']'
                        FROM [AccountDetailsDerived]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')

    SELECT @MonthRate = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[EFF_DT_RATE]) + ']'
                        FROM [AccountDetailsDerived]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')
```

I fill the Query variables with two pivots one for each month pattern:

```
    SET @Query = 'SELECT [ACC_NO],' + @MonthBal + ', '+ @MonthRate +' from 
                 [AccountDetailsDerived]
                pivot 
                (
                    max([BAL])
                    for [EFF_DT_BAL] in (' + @MonthBal + ')
                ) p 
                pivot
                (
                    max([RATE])
                    for [EFF_DT_RATE] in (' + @MonthRate + ')
                ) p2 '
```

Now when I execute the query I get the desired resultset (the nulls can be handled further which I have not done)

```
    EXEC(@Query)
```

The Resultset:

```
    ACC_NO  | 2006-01-01 BAL    | 2006-01-02 BAL    | 2006-01-05 BAL    | 2006-01-01 RATE   | 2006-01-02 RATE   | 2006-01-05 RATE
    1001    | NULL              | 12000             | NULL              | NULL              | 4.25              | NULL
    1001    | 10000             | NULL              | NULL              | 3.50              | NULL              | NULL
    1002    | NULL              | NULL              | 11500             | NULL              | NULL              | 4.75
    1002    | NULL              | 11000             | NULL              | NULL              | 3.25              | NULL
    1003    | NULL              | NULL              | 0                 | NULL              | NULL              | 0.00
    1003    | 35000             | NULL              | NULL              | 3.50              | NULL              | NULL
```

The whole script is as:

```
    BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE     @MonthBal   VARCHAR(MAX)
        ,       @MonthRate  VARCHAR(MAX)
        ,       @Query  VARCHAR(MAX)


    CREATE TABLE [AccountDetails]
    (
        [ACC_NO]    INT
    ,   [BAL]       INT
    ,   [RATE]      DECIMAL(18, 2)
    ,   [EFF_DT]    DATE
    )

    CREATE TABLE [AccountDetailsDerived]
    (
        [ACC_NO]        INT
    ,   [BAL]           INT
    ,   [RATE]          DECIMAL(18, 2)
    ,   [EFF_DT_BAL]    VARCHAR(50)
    ,   [EFF_DT_RATE]   VARCHAR(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO [AccountDetails]
    (
        [ACC_NO]
    ,   [BAL]
    ,   [RATE]
    ,   [EFF_DT]
    )
    VALUES
        (1001,    10000,   3.5,     '01/01/2006')
    ,   (1001,    12000,   4.25,    '01/02/2006')
    ,   (1002,    11000,   3.25,    '01/02/2006')
    ,   (1002,    11500,   4.75,    '01/05/2006')
    ,   (1003,    35000,   3.5,     '01/01/2006')
    ,   (1003,    0,       0,       '01/05/2006')

    INSERT INTO [AccountDetailsDerived]
    (
        [ACC_NO]        
    ,   [BAL]           
    ,   [RATE]          
    ,   [EFF_DT_BAL]    
    ,   [EFF_DT_RATE]   
    )
    SELECT  [ACC_NO]
        ,   [BAL]   
        ,   [RATE]  
        ,   CONVERT(VARCHAR, [EFF_DT] ) + ' BAL'
        ,   CONVERT(VARCHAR, [EFF_DT] ) + ' RATE'
    FROM    [AccountDetails]

    SELECT * FROM [AccountDetailsDerived]

    SELECT @MonthBal = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[EFF_DT_BAL]) + ']'
                        FROM [AccountDetailsDerived]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')

    SELECT @MonthRate = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[EFF_DT_RATE]) + ']'
                        FROM [AccountDetailsDerived]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')

    PRINT @MonthBal
    PRINT @MonthRate

    SET @Query = 'SELECT [ACC_NO],' + @MonthBal + ', '+ @MonthRate +' from 
                 [AccountDetailsDerived]
                pivot 
                (
                    max([BAL])
                    for [EFF_DT_BAL] in (' + @MonthBal + ')
                ) p 
                pivot
                (
                    max([RATE])
                    for [EFF_DT_RATE] in (' + @MonthRate + ')
                ) p2 '


    PRINT(@Query)
    EXEC(@Query)

    ROLLBACK
```

**Thats it!**